# Laplacian matrix and its eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-laplacian, derivation-of-formulae

I am reading [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0605087.pdf) written by Newman on finding community structure in a network.

I came across with the Laplacian matrix. And there is one equation derived from some others.
Before diving into that, I define some important notations. Let **B** be $n\times n$ laplacian matrix defined on an undirected complete graph $G=(V,E)$ and $\textbf{x}_1,\textbf{x}_2,\textbf{x}_3,...,\textbf{x}_n$ are eigenvectors correspondent to $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,...,\lambda_n$ eigenvalues. And vector **s** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is define as
$$
     s_{i} = \begin{cases}
    1, &  \text{vertex} \space i \space\text{belongs to group 1,}\\
   -1 &\text{otherwise }. 
\end{cases}
$$
Here, groups are (there are two groups), for the sake of simplicity, based on an arbitrary division of graph $G$.

Using properties of symmetric matrices, it is possible to state that $\textbf{B}\textbf{x}_i = \lambda_i\textbf{x}_i$ and $\textbf{x}^T_{i}\textbf{x}_i=1$. Now let us write **s** as a linear combination: $\textbf{s}=\sum_{i=1}^n{\alpha_i\textbf{x}_i}$, where $\alpha_i=\textbf{x}^T_i\textbf{s}$.

In a paper it was said that to find the number of required edges to disconnect graph into two groups, the following equality holds.
$$
\frac{1}{4}\textbf{s}^T\textbf{B}\textbf{s}.
$$

And later an author provided the further derivation:
$$
\frac{1}{4}\textbf{s}^T\textbf{B}\textbf{s}=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_i{}\alpha_i\textbf{x}_i^T \textbf{B}\frac{1}{4}\sum_j{}\alpha_j\textbf{x}_j=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{ij}\alpha_i\alpha_j\lambda_j\delta_{ij}=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_i{\alpha_i^2\lambda_i}.
$$

I wonder is it possible to derive $\frac{1}{4}\sum_i{\alpha_i^2\lambda_i}$ using the following process?

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sum_i\alpha_i\textbf{x}_i^T \textbf{B}\frac{1}{4}\sum_j\alpha_j\textbf{x}_j=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_i \alpha_i\textbf{x}_i^T \textbf{B} \alpha_i\textbf{x}_i = 
\frac{1}{4}\sum_i \alpha_i\textbf{x}_i^T \textbf{B} \textbf{x}_i\alpha_i=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_i \alpha_i\lambda_i\alpha_i = \frac{1}{4}\sum_i{\alpha_i^2\lambda_i}
$$

Comment: I don't think this will do. The only way I can get your first equality is essentially by using the author's correct derivation and then working backwards along yours. But I think you are missing some basic facts here: what is important is that the $x_i$ are orthogonal, that is $x_i^Tx_j=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @ancient mathematician I tried to derive the final term with different approches. Unfortunately, I every time ended up with failure. Could you specifically show the intermediate steps from $\frac{1}{4}\sum_i{\alpha_i \textbf{x}_i^T} \textbf{B} \sum_j{\alpha_j \textbf{x}_j}$ to $\frac{1}{4}\sum_i{\alpha_i^2\lambda_i}$?

Comment: I am completely at a loss to understand what your problem is: the author's derivation is short and clear (provided you know the key linear algebra fact that we have a basis of eigenvectors $x_1,\dots, x_n$ which satisfies $x_i^Tx_j=\delta_{ij}$).